# How to Create a Bumped Logo with Flickering Light Animation in Blender?

Tags: bump

Hello Blender community,

I'm relatively new to Blender and I'm trying to recreate a specific animation effect for a logo, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to achieve it. I've seen a video where a logo is both bumped up and flickering with light, and I would like to replicate that effect in Blender.

Here's a breakdown of what I'm trying to achieve:

Bumped Logo: I want my logo to appear as if it's slightly bumped up, giving it a 3D appearance, but not a full 3D model. I've tried using displacement modifiers and bump maps, but I'm not sure if that's the right approach or if there's a better way.

Flickering Light: I also want the logo to have a flickering light effect as if it's being illuminated by a light source that is intermittently turning on and off. This should create a dynamic and eye-catching visual.

To give you a clearer idea of what I have in mind, here's a link to an example video that demonstrates the effect I'm trying to achieve: https://www.instagram.com/p/CTKUspCljEa/

If anyone could provide some guidance on how to approach these two aspects of the animation or suggest tutorials/resources that might help, I would greatly appreciate it. Additionally, if there are any specific settings or techniques I should be aware of in Blender to achieve this effect, please let me know.

Thank you in advance for your help!

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: the logo thickness seems to be rather thin, or even engraved on a surface, you need to convert an svg to mesh and give it a bit of thickness or extrusion, depending on what you choose. For the material I guess a simple BSDF with Metallic at 1 is enough. As for the light just switch it on and off?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I added a GIF image featuring the result I'm after. Actually I'm wondering if there is a way to achieve such result using Blender.

Answer (score 1):

Find the logo in b&w, convert to mesh, use it to cut a plane surface with the *Knife Project* tool:

[image]

It should give something like that:

[image]

Remove the logo, extrude the carving that has been created:

[image]

Give 2 materials to your object, a dense black and a gold material:

[image]